# Particular WiFi does not connect after trying to root Samsung Galaxy S10e with Magisk

Tags: wi-fi, rooting, magisk, samsung-galaxy-s-10

I followed this tutorial: https://topjohnwu.github.io/Magisk/samsung

All went well until step 14 (so, right after flashing the ROM and rebooting).

At step 14, Magisk tried updating, but could not. I realized the problem was that Android can not connect to my company's WiFi. I mean, I can see the WiFi networks, but I can not log into my company's WiFi.

Notes:

- The WiFi hotspot itself is OK, my desktop computer is using it right now to post this question.
- Android was able to connect to that WiFi and use its Internet, up to step 5 at least.
- Strangely, I can connect to another WiFi network (my friend's mobile tethering)
- [This thread](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/wifi-problems-caused-magisk-t3606988) suggests it might be caused by modules, and suggest removing the modules then rebooting, but I installed no modules.

How to fix the problem?

## adb logcat

```
05-21 22:20:33.559  5207  5207 D WifiHAL : Start get packet fate command                                                                                                                            
05-21 22:20:33.559  5207  5207 D WifiHAL : createRequest Get Tx packet fate request                                           
05-21 22:20:33.559  5207  5207 D WifiHAL : error code -95 mapped to -3                                                                                                                              
05-21 22:20:33.559  5207  5207 E WifiHAL : Failed to register get pkt fate response; result = -3                                                                                                    
05-21 22:20:33.559  5608  5873 E WifiVendorHal: getTxPktFates(l.2241) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }                                                                         
05-21 22:20:33.560  5207  5207 D WifiHAL : Start get packet fate command                                                                                                                            
05-21 22:20:33.560  5207  5207 D WifiHAL : createRequest Get Rx packet fate request                                                                                                                 
05-21 22:20:33.560  5207  5207 D WifiHAL : error code -95 mapped to -3                                                                                                                              
05-21 22:20:33.560  5207  5207 E WifiHAL : Failed to register get pkt fate response; result = -3                                                                                                  
05-21 22:20:33.560  5608  5873 E WifiVendorHal: getRxPktFates(l.2283) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, .description = }
```

I also get:

```
WifiVendorHal: getRingBufferStatus(l.2059) failed {.code = ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED,
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to the WiFi networks activity.
2. Long-press the problematic WiFi network
3. Choose "Forget network"
4. Turn WiFi off and on, just to make sure
5. Tap the WiFi
6. You will be asked for the WiFi password again, enter it
7. Now you should be able to connect, at least that is what worked for me